# How can I map elements of a data frame into another data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have the following two data frames.
Data frame 1:

| Basket | Apple | Banana | Citrus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C01 | A03 | C02 |
| 2 | A01 | B02 | C03 |
| 3 | B01 | A02 | B03 |

Data frame 2 has row names labeled A-C and with column names labeled 1-3.

How am I able to read the elements from data frame 1, and map them into their respective cells in data frame two. For instance, if the element in df1 reads as C01, it would be printed into data frame 2 row C column 1 with the following string: 'Apple1' (apple in basket 1).

Example of the end goal:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Apple2 | Banana3 | Banana1 |
| B | Apple3 | Banana2 | Citrus3 |
| C | Apple1 | Citrus1 | Citrus2 |

Comment: You do not need the rstudio tag here. also please share your data in a readable format so others can help. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We reshape the data into 'long' format using the columns other than 'Basket', `separate` the 'value' column into two by splitting at the junction between the non-numeric and numeric part, `unite` the 'name' column with 'Basket' and reshape to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -Basket) %>%
    separate(value, into = c('col1', 'col2'), 
            sep="(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)", convert = TRUE) %>% 
    unite(name, name, Basket, sep="") %>% 
    arrange(col2, col1) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = col2, values_from = name)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  col1  `1`    `2`     `3`    
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  
#1 A     Apple2 Banana3 Banana1
#2 B     Apple3 Banana2 Citrus3
#3 C     Apple1 Citrus1 Citrus2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Basket = 1:3, Apple = c("C01", "A01", "B01"), 
    Banana = c("A03", "B02", "A02"), Citrus = c("C02", "C03", 
    "B03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun! Would this method also be valid if the original data frame was potentially extended and also had some NULL or N/A cells?

Comment: @NickL `NULL` cannot exist in a vector.  Perhaps you meant `"NULL"` instead of `NULL` and `NA` is without `/`.  If there are `NA`, then we use `values_drop_na = TRUE` in `pivot_longer` to remove those NA elements

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option using `dcast` + `melt`

```
dcast(
  melt(setDT(df1),
    id.var = "Basket"
  )[
    ,
    variable := paste0(variable, Basket)
  ],
  gsub("\\d", "", value) ~ gsub("\\D", "", value),
  value.var = "variable"
)
```

gives

```
   value     01      02      03
1:     A Apple2 Banana3 Banana1
2:     B Apple3 Banana2 Citrus3
3:     C Apple1 Citrus1 Citrus2
```